# Parsing nested ternary expressions

Tags: python, pyparsing

The continuation of my PyParsing quest is parsing nested ternary expressions (e.g. `(x == 1 ? true : (y == 10 ? 100 : 200))`). As such, I constructed the following expression. Which, to me, seems intuitive. However I get no matches:

```
any = Word(printables)

conditional = Forward()
sub_exp = (conditional | any)
conditional = Literal('(') + sub_exp + Literal('?') + sub_exp + Literal(':') + sub_exp + Literal(')')

    for exp in conditional.scanString(block_str):
        print exp
```

Initially I thought that the problem was with printables consuming everything; I set the excludeChars to not match `:?)(`, but that didn't help either. The alternative was to construct nested expressions, one each for the "*( ?*", "*? :* " and "*: )*" blocks. But this approach is very messy. Does anybody have any recommendations on parsing ternary expressions?

**UPDATE**
Using the answer from below, but modified to work with scanString:

When using scanString however, it returns a lot of other matches too (basically, anything matching atom).

```
lpar = Literal('(').suppress()
rpar = Literal(')').suppress()
any = Combine(OneOrMore(Word(printables, excludeChars='()?:') | White(' ', max=1)))
expr = Forward()
atom = any | Group(lpar + expr + Literal('?') + expr + Literal(':') + expr + rpar)
expr << Literal('(') + atom + ZeroOrMore(expr) + Literal('?') + atom + ZeroOrMore(expr) + Literal(':') + atom + ZeroOrMore(expr) + Literal(')')

for ternary_exp in expr.scanString(block_str):
  print ternary_exp
```

Comment: Maybe it's a spacing issue. Does your expression match "`( x == 1 ? true : ( y == 10 ? 100 : 200 ) )`"?

Comment: Nope, to no avail. No matches (and no errors).

Comment: You are assigning to `conditional` twice, is that intended? Also, I would define an expression placeholder which is what your `(conditional | any)` is above and which can be tested separately. BTW: Which of the parts that you use match separately?

Comment: Thanks Ulrich. I updated the post: sub_exp = (conditional | any)

sub_exp matches separately.

Comment: To define the expression for a previously-declared Forward, use the '<<=' or '<<' operator, not '='.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I don't quite understand why I should use bitwise operators / shifts. Could you explain?

Comment: I think they are not bitwise shifts but rather overloaded for the sake of pyparsing. You have to consider that your definition is recursive, so the definition of a `conditional` must reference itself~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of arithmetic expression parsing, try using pyparsing's builtin `infixNotation` (formerly known as `operatorPrecedence`):

```
from pyparsing import *

integer = Word(nums)
variable = Word(alphas, alphanums)
boolLiteral = oneOf("true false")

operand = boolLiteral | variable | integer

comparison_op = oneOf("== <= >= != < >")
QM,COLON = map(Literal,"?:")
expr = infixNotation(operand,
    [
    (comparison_op, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    ((QM,COLON), 3, opAssoc.LEFT),
    ])

print expr.parseString("(x==1? true: (y == 10? 100 : 200) )")
```

Prints

```
[[['x', '==', '1'], '?', 'true', ':', [['y', '==', '10'], '?', '100', ':', '200']]]
```

`infixNotation` takes care of all of the recursive expressions, and resolves precedence of operations and overriding of that precedence using ()'s.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is two-fold: the whitespace (which isn't handled well by your `any` definition), and the recursion (which should use the `<<` operator):

```
lpar  = Literal( '(' ).suppress()
rpar  = Literal( ')' ).suppress()
any = Combine(OneOrMore(Word(printables, excludeChars='()?:') | White(' ',max=1)))
expr = Forward()
atom = any | Group( lpar + expr + Literal('?') + expr + Literal(':') + expr + rpar )
expr << atom + ZeroOrMore( expr )
```

For example,

```
t2 = '(x == 1 ? true : (y == 10 ? 100 : 200))'
expr.parseString(t2)
([(['x == 1 ', '?', 'true ', ':', (['y == 10 ', '?', '100 ', ':', '200'], {})], {})], {})
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified my post with your answer.

Comment: Much though I appreciate the upvotes, the other answer is by the lead developer of `pyparsing` so perhaps ought to be the accepted one.

Comment: OK :-) I found your solution easier to understand. But reading up on infixNotation, I guess his solution is the "more correct way" of doing it. Thank you xnx!